# After installing some npm module globally shows a long list of errors when I list them! How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, eslint, npm-install

After installing some npm module globally shows a long list of errors/ missing dependencies when I list them! How to fix it?

Packages I have installed :

- eslint
- gatsby-cli
- gulp
- heroku
- node-gyp
- npm-install-peers
- yarn

Show this Error when I list the packages:

```
Command: npm list -g --depth 0 
C:\Users\Sahil Ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- eslint@7.5.0
+-- gatsby-cli@2.12.66
+-- gulp@4.0.2
+-- heroku@7.42.5
+-- node-gyp@7.0.0
+-- npm-install-peers@1.2.1
`-- yarn@1.22.4

npm ERR! peer dep missing: acorn@^6.0.0, required by acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0
npm ERR! missing: @babel/code-frame@^7.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-scope@^5.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: espree@^6.1.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esquery@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: functional-red-black-tree@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: ignore@^4.0.6, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: import-fresh@^3.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: imurmurhash@^0.1.4, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: levn@^0.3.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: natural-compare@^1.4.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: progress@^2.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: regexpp@^2.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: table@^5.2.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: text-table@^0.2.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: v8-compile-cache@^2.0.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-deep-equal@^2.0.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-json-stable-stringify@^2.0.0, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: json-schema-traverse@^0.4.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: uri-js@^4.2.2, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by doctrine@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint-utils@1.4.3
npm ERR! missing: flatted@^2.0.0, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.3, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: type-fest@^0.8.1, required by globals@12.3.0
npm ERR! missing: cli-width@^2.0.0, required by inquirer@7.0.0
npm ERR! missing: deep-is@~0.1.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: levn@~0.3.0, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: prelude-ls@~1.1.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: type-check@~0.3.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: word-wrap@~1.2.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: @babel/code-frame@^7.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-scope@^5.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: espree@^6.1.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esquery@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: functional-red-black-tree@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: ignore@^4.0.6, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: import-fresh@^3.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: imurmurhash@^0.1.4, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: levn@^0.3.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: natural-compare@^1.4.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: progress@^2.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: regexpp@^2.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: table@^5.2.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: text-table@^0.2.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: v8-compile-cache@^2.0.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-deep-equal@^2.0.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-json-stable-stringify@^2.0.0, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: json-schema-traverse@^0.4.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: uri-js@^4.2.2, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by doctrine@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint-utils@1.4.3
npm ERR! missing: mimic-fn@^2.1.0, required by onetime@5.1.0
npm ERR! missing: flatted@^2.0.0, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.3, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: type-fest@^0.8.1, required by globals@12.3.0
npm ERR! missing: deep-is@~0.1.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: levn@~0.3.0, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: prelude-ls@~1.1.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: type-check@~0.3.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: word-wrap@~1.2.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: chai@^4.1.2, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: deep-equal@^1.0.0, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: json-stringify-safe@^5.0.1, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: propagate@^1.0.0, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: qs@^6.5.1, required by nock@9.6.1
```

Tried Reinstalling All Packages but Still occurs.

Do I have to download all the dependencies or I shouldn't have installed some package globally?

Comment: Don't install packages globally. Use [npx](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b) or project dependencies instead.

Comment: @rveerd, I think the same to resolve this issue or maybe it's with my os config; Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `--depth 0` prevents the installation of dependencies.
Dependencies are what the modules you are trying to install rely on to work. Not installing them means your modules won't work.

Remove the parameter and it should work properly.

Comment: I don't use `--depth 0` while installation; Even if I list without `--depth 0` it's still logs error!